# About the ambiguity of using a name vs using a namespace when doing unqualified calls

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++17, language-lawyer, using-directives

I knew that this would be ambiguous

```cpp
#include <boost/hana/fwd/equal.hpp>
#include <range/v3/algorithm/equal.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
    using namespace boost::hana;
    using namespace ranges;
    equal(v, v);
}
```

because there's an `equal` both in `boost::hana` and `ranges` namespaces.

However, I thought this would be ambiguous too:

```cpp
#include <boost/hana/fwd/equal.hpp>
#include <range/v3/algorithm/equal.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
    using namespace boost::hana;
    using ranges::equal;
    equal(v, v);
}
```

But that's not the case, according to [GCC and Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/afYx9Yhxh).

Why is that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48356856/817643

Comment: https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/12/21/using-directive/

Comment: _using-declarations_, like most declarations, are simply found by lookup when the scope containing the declaration is searched. _using-directives_ «work» in much different way. Such code examples are very useful to understand what [this intricate wording](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.unqual#2.2) means.

Comment: Not sure if the dup target is relevant, though. That question (and answer) is about qualified lookup, whilst this is about unqualified.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer, oh, that's true! I've misread :(

Comment: C++ doesn't stumble immediately if a name can be found in multiple namespaces. C++ will try overload resolution to resolve the ambiguity. I think the first example is ambiguosu because both `boost::hana` and `ranges` have an `equal(std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>)` function. (i.e. both perfect matches).

Comment: @MSalters, it certaily overload resolution is the logic to (try) find the match to use among several; in this case, there is an ambiguity. The question is: why doesn't the ambiguity exist in the second snippet?

Answer (score 2):

##### Snippet 2

Lets look at how the second snippet in your example works since you already know the reason for why the first snippet produces ambiguous error.

From [Using directives' documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-directives):

> Using-directives are allowed only in namespace scope and in block scope. From the point of view of **unqualified name lookup** of any name after a using-directive and until the end of the scope in which it appears, **every name from namespace-name is visible as if it were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace** which contains both the using-directive and namespace-name.
>
> **Using-directive does not add any names to the declarative region in which it appears** (unlike the using-declaration), and thus does not prevent identical names from being declared.

This means that a `using directive` does not introduce name in the declarative region (which is nothing but the `main` function in your example), but instead to the nearest enclosing namespace( which is the `global namespace` in your example).

Now, when **unqualified lookup happens** for the call expression `equal(v, v);` the search goes upwards from the point where the call expression was encountered and it finds the `equal` version that was introduced due to the `using declaration` in the declarative region(which is `main`) and hence the search stops. And so this already found version is used.

A contrived example might help clarify the situation:

```
#include <iostream>
namespace X 
{
    void func(){std::cout<<"X version called"<<std::endl;}
}
namespace Y 
{
    void func(){std::cout<<"Y version called"<<std::endl;};
}
int main()
{
    using namespace X;
    using Y::func;
    
    func(); //calls Y version
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/6D8wtKs7mv)

---

##### Snippet 1

Snippet 1 in your example can also be understood based upon the quoted statement above. In particular, you're getting ambiguous error in snippet 1 because both the namespaces `ranges` and `boost::hana` have a function called `equal` that are **equally** ranked. So when the **unqualified name lookup** happens for the *call expression* `equal(v,v)` the search starts and goes upwards from the point where the call expression was encountered and finds functions named `equal` that were made visible in the global namescope due to both of the namespaces. Moreover, since both are equally ranked, we get the mentioned ambiguous error.

A contrived example might help clarify the situation:

```
#include <iostream>
namespace X 
{
    void func(int)
    {
        std::cout<<"X version func called"<<std::endl;
    }
    
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout<<"X version foo called"<<std::endl;
    }
}
namespace Y 
{
    void func(double)
    {
        std::cout<<"Y version func called"<<std::endl;
    }
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout<<"Y version foo called"<<std::endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    using namespace X ;
    using namespace Y;
    
    func(3); //calls X's func 
    func(5.5);//calls Y's func
    
    foo();//fails due to ambiguity
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/OajeYyNOB)