# How does "using std::cout" runs successfully while "using namespace std" does not in the below example?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was going through the Namespace topics and found that when we compile the below code
the compiler complaints

> `[Error] reference to 'cout' is ambiguous`

```
#include <iostream> 

void cout() 
{
 std::cout << "In cout function\n";
}

int main()
{
using namespace std; 
cout << "Hello, world!\n";
return 0;
}
```

But if we replace `using namespace std` with `using std::cout`, the program runs successfully and produces the expected output. How is this possible?

```
#include <iostream> 

int cout() 
{
std::cout << "In cout function\n";
}

int main()
{
using std::cout;  //REPLACED 
cout << "Hello, world!\n";
return 0;
}
```

As far as I am aware the only difference between `using std::cout` and `using namespace std`
is,

`using std::cout` -> imports only `cout` from std namespace, while

`using namespace std` -> imports all the variables from `std`.

In both of the cases `cout()` function and `std::cout` variable are visible within main function. So how is `using std::cout` resolving the issue while `using namespace std` is not able to?

Comment: Neither is an import. I'm afraid experience in other languages is a disadvantage here, because C++ is very peculiar in this regard. See [Using directive vs using declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48356856/817643) for example.

Comment: You can't learn c++ by trial and error. It must be learnt using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Read about using directive and using declaration.

Comment: Also see dupe: [About the ambiguity of using a name vs using a namespace when doing unqualified calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71690024/about-the-ambiguity-of-using-a-name-vs-using-a-namespace-when-doing-unqualified) where this is explained in very detail.

Comment: @spectras possibly because first related question is immediately "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice?rq=2"  ... and one of first reasons is getting compiling errors about ambiguity.

Comment: Duplicate of [About the ambiguity of using a name vs using a namespace when doing unqualified calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71690024/about-the-ambiguity-of-using-a-name-vs-using-a-namespace-when-doing-unqualified) and [Using directive vs using declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48356856/817643)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [About the ambiguity of using a name vs using a namespace when doing unqualified calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71690024/about-the-ambiguity-of-using-a-name-vs-using-a-namespace-when-doing-unqualified)

Answer (score 3):

Informally:

`using std::cout` means "in this scope, the identifier `cout` refers specifically to `std::cout`, so don't go looking anywhere else for it".

`using namespace std` means "add all the names in `std` to the current scope, in addition to everything else that is also in scope".

In the first case, you have explicitly said that `cout` means `std::cout`– the global `cout` is hidden and there can be no ambiguity.

In the second case, `cout` is ambiguous since it can refer to either `std::cout` or your function.

You will see similar errors in the first case if you try to declare your function inside `main`:

```
int main()
{
    int cout();
    using std::cout;
    cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    return 0;
}
```